# Is Relief Mapping techniques being used these days?

Tags: texture, mapping

I've been researching for some time now the Relief Texture Mapping ([https://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~oliveira/RTM.html](https://www.inf.ufrgs.br/%7Eoliveira/RTM.html)), and I'm trying to identify implementations of this technique and its improvements in the industry (mainly game engines and rendering softwares) but I can't find anything about it.

Do the usual methodologies have a better cost benefit? What is this based on? Are there difficulties in implementing this technique such as lack of a tool or optimizations?

Answer (score 3):

"Relief Texture Mapping" is comparable to "Parallax Occlusion Mapping" (POM). POM is common in rendering systems/games and more popular then the "Relief Texture Mapping" technique mostly because it is easier to implement, has better documentation, and tends to perform better. I have an old relief mapping shader for GLSL that I could post if you are interested. But I suggest looking into Parallax Mapping instead.

Relief Texture Mapping usually produces better results and has a lot of extensions. But POM has the edge on efficiency and produces "good enough" results.